# Crystal Reports XI Server Edition

Tags: crystal-reports

We have Crystal Report XI installed on a virtual server.  I can access the CMC and InfoView with out a problem.  I can create a CR locally and load it on the server fine.  As long as my report does not need ODBC drivers on the server.  My questions deals with the way this set up should work.  the idea was to have users from different departments access the server and create their own reports on the fly.  Problem is how do we access a developer windo from the server?  What software do I need to create a Universe?  Is our intended set up of CR on the server the correct way it was intended to be used?  That is having users write the reports.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the web-based "Crystal Management Console" installed? This is the web-app you'll use to add reports that you have created with Crystal Reports (Crystal Reports XI Second Release SP5 is the newest version, still available for download from SAP's website).

Through the management console, you can determine the datasource and the credentials to be used by the Report. Those can be stored on the server, and every user will be able to run the report (because required credentials are already stored on server).

You can also use the management console to organize your reports into folders for each departments.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  We do have Central Management Console installed.  It is web based, and I use it to add reports, manage users, groups, objects,…
I was under the impression that users that is report writers, can access Crystal Reports designer via the server.  They can then create their own reports without CR installed on their PC.  Is this true and if so how?  Under the Manage area of the CMC there is ‘Business Objects Enterprise Applications’ and from there I can set properties and rights for the designer but how do I access the designer itself?

Comment: Also, I can write a report using crystal on my desktop and move it to the server.  My reports however use ODBC drivers which are not on the server.  I am assuming I will have to install the drivers on the server for the reports to run.

Comment: How do I create a Universe?  What application do I use for Universe creation?  Any help/comments would be appreciated.